# SqlServerCe writing to C:\ProgramData

Tags: sql-server-ce

My program is writing to a SqlServerCe file located at `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\MyDb.sdf`.
For development I've made my account the owner of `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\` with write access.

Previously this has been working fine but today I got this error:

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.400.32.bc' is denied.'**

[image: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.400.32.bc' is denied.']

With this stack trace

```
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(string path, bool append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, int bufferSize, bool checkHost)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(string path, bool append, System.Text.Encoding encoding)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] contents, System.Text.Encoding encoding)    Unknown
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll!System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeServicing.DoBreadcrumbServicing(string modulePath) Unknown
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll!System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder(string privateInstall)    Unknown
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll!System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()  Unknown
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll!System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.SqlCeConnection()   Unknown
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll!System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.SqlCeConnection(string connectionString)    Unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that although SqlServerCe does try to write to 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.400.32.bc' failing to do so isn't a critical error.

The program could safely continue by pressing "Continue"/F5

The reason Visual Studio did break was this setting.

[image: Break when this exception type is thrown]